# Error with setting Date in EditText

Tags: android

I have made DatePicker with dialog. When I set date from dialog my program crashes and says "Unffortunately prgram has stopped". This is my code:

```
package com.example.reminder;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public EditText editText;
    DatePicker dpResult;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    editText.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
            + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    // set selected date into datepicker also


}
}
```

I know that the problem is in `onDateSet` method. Can someone help?

My LogCat:

```
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at com.example.reminder.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.java:38)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:116)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-05 12:19:40.702: E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 12:19:44.152: E/Trace(2899): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: post what your logcat displays when application crashes...

Comment: initialized edittext? You have not initialized editext

Comment: I edited my question now there is LogCat

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid you can use the below as reference. have you defined editext in your xml? If you have a fragment inflate the fragment initialize edittext and then set the date to edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edittext is not initialized.

You will get null pointer exception since you edittext is not initialized.

Use the below for reference. On button click date picker pops up. Choose the date and click set and the date is set to edittext.

Example:

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

pickerdate class

```
   public class pickerdate extends Activity {

  static EditText mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mDateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });


    }


    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public EditText editText;
        DatePicker dpResult;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        mDateDisplay .setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        // set selected date into datepicker also


    }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid you are welcome. i have used a activity you can also use a fragment. modify the above according to your requirement's

Comment: wtf is wrong with you @BeginnerAndroid? You told it wasn't an initialization problem and then accept an answer that solves an initialization problem??

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid seems some one downvoted without posting a reason as a comment.

Comment: in any case i also posted the problem in the comment section before any one posted the answer. And i had a working sample and posted the same. If you are using fragments you will have to inflate then intialize and then use edittext. The sample uses activity.

Answer (score 1):

Your `editText` is not initialized, is an empty (null) variable.

Where is that `editText` visible?

If you have your `editText` declared in the layout file, get the `editText` in the layout with this code:

`editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);`

I assume that the EditText in your layout file is named `editText`.

Comment: Okey I will make new question

Comment: NullPointerException means that an element is null (empty, not initialized), seems that the problem is what I said. If is not the problem, then put the line of code where you initialize `editText`, because in the code you posted is not initialized.

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid In the first comment you mentioned it wasn't a initialization problem, but at the end it was.

Comment: I answered first with the problem and then other gets the accept points :-/ Always the same :-/